# Wired connection to LAN but no internet after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, ethernet

I have a wired connection to LAN but no internet after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04. Wireless connection is working fine.

```
    ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:2a:72:be:81:8b  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:612 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:81397 (81.3 KB)  TX bytes:50754 (50.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:29634 (29.6 KB)  TX bytes:29634 (29.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:ad:97:02:78:e7  
          inet addr:10.145.160.47  Bcast:10.145.255.255  Mask:255.255.128.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9ead:97ff:fe02:78e7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:758982 (758.9 KB)  TX bytes:153922 (153.9 KB)
```

After connecting to wired connection

```
    ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:2a:72:be:81:8b  
          inet addr:192.168.0.104  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba2a:72ff:febe:818b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:925 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:724 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:92209 (92.2 KB)  TX bytes:62148 (62.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:805 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:805 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:104784 (104.7 KB)  TX bytes:104784 (104.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:ad:97:02:78:e7  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2508410 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:876197 (876.1 KB)
```

Comment: Did you try to disconnect WiFi and plug the LAN cable? If you did it, `eth0` had an IP assigned?

Comment: In terminal, what response do you get to `ping 8.8.8.8` and `host www.ebay.com`? Cheers, Al

Comment: 'Destination Net Unreachable' and 'Connection timed out: no servers could be reached' respectively.                                                                                                                         Also, i am using proxy server.

Comment: Your wired eth0 gets an IP so looks like everything is fine with Ubuntu. Try pinging it's default gateway get it from `netstat -rn` if you can ping default gateway look into your proxy

Comment: Problem was with proxy setting . Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same exact issue and found that in my case, it was Kernel that needed to be updated.

First download the packages. This one is for 64 bit.

```
$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9-rc2/linux-headers-4.9.0-040900rc2_4.9.0-040900rc2.201610232131_all.deb

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9-rc2/linux-headers-4.9.0-040900rc2-generic_4.9.0-040900rc2.201610232131_amd64.deb

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9-rc2/linux-image-4.9.0-040900rc2-generic_4.9.0-040900rc2.201610232131_amd64.deb
```

Next, install the packages.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i 'linux-headers-4.9*.deb' 'linux-image-4.9*.deb'
```

And finally, reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

Here are the packages for 32 bit machines.

```
$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9-rc2/linux-headers-4.9.0-040900rc2_4.9.0-040900rc2.201610232131

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9-rc2/linux-headers-4.9.0-040900rc2-generic_4.9.0-040900rc2.201610232131_i386.deb

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9-rc2/linux-image-4.9.0-040900rc2-generic_4.9.0-040900rc2.201610232131_i386.deb
```

Install the packages.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i 'linux-headers-4.9*.deb' 'linux-image-4.9*.deb'
```

Reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

If that doesn't work, you can uninstall with the this code:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'linux-headers-4.9*' 'linux-image-4.9*'
```